# Host gitbook inside a folder in github

Tags: github, gitbook

I want to create a gitbook using markdowns available in my github repo. .I've created a folder inside github for this purpose and arranged the structure as gitbook needs.

I tried to create new book [here](https://www.gitbook.com/new) by importing the path to [my subfolder where gitbook](https://github.com/kteza1/HomeNextGen/tree/master/book) is present but this isn't working. Please let me know how to host gitbook directly in my github where my project sources are present.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to use `gh-pages` for the gitbook. (Look here: https://pages.github.com/)

Then you can make the gitbook via `gitbook build ./ ./../gh-pages` and in a separate branch you have your own gitbook.

You can look at my gitbook (https://github.com/13abylon/gamebook). I did the same thing

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want the users of repo should be able push source changes and documentation with a single push. With your method, users should first change code, switch to gh-pages branch. Add documentation there and push both.

Comment: I do it this way: I push in the normal repo and than use my makefile to do everything else for me. So I only have to push and type "make commit" afterwards (see: https://github.com/13abylon/gamebook/blob/master/Makefile#L1-L15)